# api facebook, asp.net mvc3,c#

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried installing `FBGraph` (the api) with

```
 install package fbgraph
```

but it didn't work. How can I install `FBGraph`?

Comment: Where did you try that?  How didn't it work?  I'm not familiar with an "install package" command related to C#.

Comment: @David Package Manager Console

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this library instead:

```
Install-Package Facebook
```

And learn more about it [here](http://csharpsdk.org/).

By the way, there is no FbGraph library on Nuget.

Comment: facebook have many api, i want fbgraph, know i 'am load the ImpactWorks.FBGraph.dll, thanks

Comment: Oh I see, you have to reference it manually in your project then. Take care :)